# Python: TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I have a func

```
f(x) = sin(x/5.0)*exp(x/10.0) + 5*exp(-x/2.0)
```

I need to solve system of linear equations

```
w0 + w1x1 + w2(x1)**2 + ... + wn(x1)**n = f(x1)
```

I solve that but I have a problem with plot it

```
from math import sin, exp
from scipy import linalg
import numpy as np

b = []
def f(x):
    return sin(x/5.0)*exp(x/10.0) + 5*exp(-x/2.0)

for i in [1, 15]:
    b.append(f(i))

A = []

for i in [1, 15]:
    ij = []
    x0 = i ** 0
    x1 = i ** 1
    ij.append(x0)
    ij.append(x1)
    A.append(ij)

matrix = np.array(A)
b = np.array(b).T

x = linalg.solve(matrix, b)
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, f(x))
```

But it returns

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`math.sin` and `math.exp` expect scalar inputs. If you pass an array, you get a `TypeError`

```
In [34]: x
Out[34]: array([ 3.43914511, -0.18692825])

In [35]: math.sin(x)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

---

`from math import sin, exp` loads `sin` and `exp` from the `math` module and defines them as functions in the global namespace. So `f(x)` is calling `math`'s version of the `sin` function on `x` which is a NumPy array:

```
def f(x):
    return sin(x/5.0)*exp(x/10.0) + 5*exp(-x/2.0)
```

---

To fix the error, use NumPy's `sin` and `exp` functions instead.

```
import numpy as np
def f(x):
    return np.sin(x/5.0)*np.exp(x/10.0) + 5*np.exp(-x/2.0)
```

Comment: Why does it happen?

Comment: The functions in the `math` module from the standard library expects scalars as inputs. The equivalent NumPy functions are designed to work with NumPy arrays. `x` is a NumPy array, so you need to use `np.sin(x)`, not `math.sin(x)`.